# Passing an expression from a LINQ Queryable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a Service Repository pattern built on top of Entity Framework.

The service has methods such as Find(IQuery query) that return IEnumerable.

The IQuery object is our own query object type where we convert strings to an IQueryable expression that the repository, which exposes IQueryable, can use.

What I'd like to do is be able to write a queryable on the client side and pass that over the service so that we can take advantage of the static typing and linq style queries instead of building our own query object in formation.

In other words I want to be able to do something like:

```
var query = new List<Type>().Where(x => x.Property == "argument").AsQueryable();
service.find(query);
```

Then I would pass the queryable or the expression it creates to my repository and work like that.

Is this sort of thing possible, or would I have to build the expression from scratch?  It seems like this should be possible, but I really don't know where to begin or see examples of how to share an expression like this.

Comment: What part of the Expression will be passed by the client? The property key? The value?

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using EF directly, because the platform that is built on top of it isn't actually adding value to you, but instead removing value.

Comment: @servy It sure would be easier that way, but the value comes from not being dependent on, and decoupled from, EF in the rest of the application.  The service and repository offer a separation of concern.

Comment: @twifosp Removing the dependency on EF only to add a dependency on an even more cumbersome querying tool seems like a step down.

Comment: You will need to provide more information about what an `IQuery` is before we can help you use it.

Comment: @servy separation of concern is never a step down in my book.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `AsQueryable()` on an `IEnumerable` that doesn't already implement `IQueryable`, then that whole enumerable is just stuffed into a `ConstantExpression`, and any previous LINQ operations are not expressed as expression trees.

If you call `AsQueryable()` right on the source, then the LINQ operations *will* return an `IQueryable` with the proper query expression tree:

```
var query = new List<Type>().AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Property == "argument");
```